# Connecting to Mongodb without Auth?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have Mongodb installed on my Ubuntu server. I allowed the server IP in the database config file. Port 27017 is open. The auth is off on the database meaning everybody is supposed to be able to connect to it via this URI string using Compass:

`mongodb://<server IP address>:27017`

with all this conditions ongoing, I still cannot connect to db with this URI string. Why?

Comment: The connection string looks ok. What error are you getting when you try to connect? Also, please try connecting with the command line interface.

Comment: somehow it started working.  i changed the default port from 27017 to 42160 in config file with auth being on and 42160 is open. restarted the service. but cannot connect. it says: `connect ETIMEDOUT <ip address>:42160`

Comment: it also does not work with new port even without db auth

Comment: change back to default port 27017

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot connect"? What is the error message?